# Why don't int("True") and float("True") work in python?

Tags: python

I was messing around in the interpreter knowing that in python, `True == 1` evaluates to `True`, which means that `int(True)` outputs `1`.

If I input `float("True")` the interpreter returns:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'True'`

if I input `int("True")` the interpreter returns:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'True'`

Why is this? Since `True` and `False` are equal to `1` and `0` respectively, shouldn't it work? What's causing the ValueError in `int()`?

Comment: remove the quotes and try

Comment: "True" is a string, different from True. Give int(True) a try.

Comment: Inside `int` or `float` there will probably be some type detection condition and if the type is a boolean it can either convert `True` to `1` or `False` to `0`. If the type is string it interprets the string as a representation of an actual number e.g. `"5"` or `"2.6"`, if it cant do that then it raises an error. There is no special treatment of the string `"True"`, it's no more valid for conversion to int or float than `"Floccinaucinihilipilification"`

Comment: Interestingly, `float(bool("True"))` will work! ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith: But not the way it initially looks like it should work, as `bool("False")` demonstrates.

Comment: @user2357112 (Yes I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` and `float` functions parse a much more restricted syntax than general Python syntax. It may be the case that the Python expression `True` evaluates to an object equal to `1`, but `int` doesn't interpret strings as Python expressions; it's trying to interpret the string as the base-10 representation of an integer. This is also why you can't do `int('2+2')` or `int('somefunction()')`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. It didn't even occur to me to try `int(2 + 2)` or experiment with other cases

Answer (score 2):

`True` is of `bool` type and
`"True"` a string type

```
int(True)
Out[2]: 1

float(True)
Out[3]: 1.0

type(True)
Out[4]: bool
```

Comment: `"5.0"`, `"nan"`, `"inf"` are all of string type; still conversion with `float()` works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "True" is evaluated as a string. So that `int(True)` and `int("True")` are not the same. Try `type(True)` and `type("True")` to confirm.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess the place it broke down for me is that `True == 1`, I'd thought that meant `int("True") == int("1")`, even if `True` is a boolean. Thanks!